# Laravel - Shared or separate pivot table for similar relationships?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, relationship

I have 2 separate many-to-many relationships, for 2 separate purposes, but they are between the same 2 tables. I'm wondering what the best practice is for organizing this?

Here's a specific example. I have a `tasks` table and a `users` table. A `task` can have many assignees (`users`), and it can also have many supervisors (`users`).

So, do I create a single `task_user` pivot table which both relationships share, and differentiate them with some extra column, let's say `type`. Then define the relationship like `$assignees = $task->users()->wherePivot('type', 'assignee');`

OR

Do I create two separate pivot tables, `assignee_task` and `supervisor_task`, and define the relationship simply as `$assignees = $task->assignees()`?

They both seem like good options to me, depending how I look at it. I'm just wondering if there's some sort of "best practice" for this situation, which I'd like to follow if there is.

Comment: is there any role on the user, as I think this separation should be made on the users table or via roles, you may have default users role and the supervisors role. that way you assign every user related with the task and distinguish between their roles on the user model. Otherwise if its not applicable I think one many to many table is enough, the second table is redundant because it's holding the same data and there is not that much benefit out of it. The major drawback with 2 tables would be that if you want to get all the users for a task you have to do 2 queries, the rest is the same.

Comment: @RinorDreshaj Yes, that first part you mentioned isn't applicable. The same users can be  either assignees or supervisors. Thanks for your opinion preferring a single shared pivot table, I think I'm going to go that route.

Comment: ... actually on second thought, I'm going to use separate tables. In my use case, I'm thinking of pivot tables as a relationship between models, rather than a relationship between tables (even though they're technically this too). With that in mind, having separate tables seems much cleaner, and more flexible if there's any future changes to one relationship and not the other